# How to draw a cirlce segments/arcs in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How can I draw a circle segment (pie segment) or arcs in draw.io? I only seem to be able to draw whole circles.

Answer (score 2):

View -> Shapes -> Other -> make sure that Infographic is selected.
Click Apply.
In the left pane, scroll to Infographic and select the first Shape ("Pie").
It has a small bug though currently.